# UL list numbering

Tags: html

I have a rather long list of points (terms of use document) and I need the numbering to go like: a,b,c...aa,bb,cc,dd etc

At the moment it goes: a,b,c...,aa,ab,ac,ad etc.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1<li>
    <li>Item 2<li>
    <li>Item 3<li>
    ... down to 26
    <li>Item 27<li>
    <li>Item 28<li>
</ul>
```

This produces

```
a. Item 1
b. Item 2
c. Item 3
... down to z.
aa. Item 27
ab. Item 28
```

Comment: What's wrong with the default sequence.. ?

Comment: Legal document has them ordered like this and the client needs the sequence to remain as per the doc.

Comment: why are you using ul instead of ol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current CSS specifications and implementations do not seem to have tools for this, even in the CSS3 Lists and Counters module (which is still a draft and largely unimplemented).

On the other hand, in a comment you wrote: “Legal document has them ordered like this and the client needs the sequence to remain as per the doc.” If that is the case, due to the usual [CSS Caveats](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css-caveats.html), you should not rely on CSS even if CSS had tools for generating such markers. Anything that *must* appear in a document should be included as *content*, not styling.

This means that you would have, say, “a.”, “b.”, …, “z.”, “aa.”, “bb.” in the content at the start of each list item. If this numbering may need to be styled separately, wrap in a text-level container, e.g.

```
<ul class=mi>
  <li><span class=marker>a.</span> item </li>
…
```

You would then have `ul.mi { list-style-stype: none; }`. The reason for using `ul` and not `ol` here is that when CSS is off, you would rather want to see bullets than numbers before your embedded markers.

Comment: I think I am going to have to go with this solution. The good thing is that it only require aa,bb,cc,dd... once in the entire terms so all the other numbering works perfectly i.e. A -> 1 -> a, A -> 1 -> b etc. Thanks for confirming it wont work aa,bb,cc out of the box

Answer (score 2):

Despite w3schools.com having a sullied reputation among many, it does serve as an "OK" reference point.

So, here's a link to their list-style-type property page.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

There are 22 different options you can go with (including "lower-alpha").  Below is an example of using dual-letter listing (aa, ab, ac) like your example (which doesn't really help you).

So, there really is no way to replicate what it is you are seeking EXCEPT if you made a CSS sprite with the format you want (aa, bb, cc, etc.) and used background-positioning (as well as append a css class to each list item) to display your letter(s).

Hope that made sense...

Answer (score 1):

The actual rendering depends on the browser ([the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) does not specify the exact numbering past the single letters).  Since you cannot customize the browser from HTML, what you want is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to achive the same numbering system (aa, bb, cc) so I use the value-attribute:

```
<ol type="a">
 <li value="27">...</li>
 <li value="54">...</li>
 <li value="81">...</li>
```

For working example see here: http://www.lexexakt.de/index.php/glossar?title=bgb0309.php

info[at]lexexakt.de